# Calculate probability of drawing at least 3 objects given certain conditions (in body paragraph)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

Just need some help solving this question, the "at least 3" instead of "exactly 3" makes this difficult, I'm not sure where to start.

Assume there are 8 bags in front of you, all containing marbles of varying colours. The probability, per bag, of randomly picking a red marble, for **bags #1 through #7 is 2%**, while the probability of randomly picking a red marble in **bag #8 is 1%**. What is the chance you will pick **at least 3** red marbles, if you're picking exactly one marble from each bag, randomly?

Comment: Consider instead the probability of the complementary event (at most $2$ reds). You can case it as
$$(0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(1,1),(2,0)$$
where the pair $(x,y)$ represents the outcome $x$ reds total from bags $1$ to $7$, and $y$ reds from bag $8$.

Comment: If you can't even start, begin by calculating the probability of drawing all red marbles.